# Does a rapid cooling step improve pasteurization of medical equipment?

Tags: microbiology, health, sterilisation

I learned that pasteurization consists of two steps: first heating and then rapid cooling. The rapid cooling was explained as "it's a thermic shock for the germs, so the ones remaining after the heating step will be definitely killed with this". But on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization#Pasteurization_process), the rapid cooling is explained as being part of a step that protect food product and it is not mentioned for the medical equipment.

I am actually asking the question to find out the best solution for this situation: let's say I am in some remote undeveloped place and I need to disinfecting a piece of equipment (*something akin to a medical equipment, not food*). I only have hot water (between about 60°C and 80° C) and cool water (both of them are clean water) in clean containers (I also have soap and have washed the equipment with it before). Will it improve the disinfecting process if I do the rapid cooling step after the heating step or is it unnecessary? If yes what procedure is the best?

Comment: Because if you continue with the heat, you'll have (partly) cooked food?

Comment: Because the remaining bacteria (pasteurisation is not sterilization) will grow fast when it is warm.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler, if it's to reduce the growth of the remaining bacteria, why isn't this cold phase mentioned for the medical equipment on the wikipedia page? is it an omission or it is really never used for pasteurizing equipment and only for food?

Comment: @MagTun because pasteurization is very different then sterilization. medical equipment is sterilized, the goal is to kill ALL bacteria.

Comment: @John but the Wikipedia mentions it for some medical equipment. Also what I have to pasteurize is not medical equipment only akin to, it doesn't need to be sterilized, just pasteurized.

Comment: @MagTun there is no cooling phase for that equipment, in fact they are heated for a long time.  the intent is to sterilize, it is just  sterilized at a lower temperature than other equipment because high heat or chemical sterilization would damage the equipment.

Comment: @John, I get uit now, for medical equipment, the pasteurization is long enough so that it doesn't only remove the parasite but really sterilizes the equipment [killing or deactivating all forms of life].  But what if I can't keeping heating long enough. I am in a remote place with limited means and I can't only keep it at around 60-70°C for 5-10min.  Would a fast cooling steps help the pasteurization by creating a thermic shock for the germs or won't affect in anyway the germs?

Answer (score 1):

They cool it fast to maintain the taste and quality and to avoid the food danger range which is 5 to 60'C, because typical pasteurization is only 99.999% effective. A fast transition through 30-40'C improves the quality a lot compared to keeping the product at 30-40'C ... If you had limited means, you could easily use extra pasteurization at the expense of the taste, and you would achieve 99.99999 percent bacteria reduction, and the slower cool would then let that figure rise by i.e. one order of magnitude.

See the conclusions here:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1541-4337.12357

To know which process best suits your equipment and product, check the tables to achieve the reduction and follow similar times:

[charts](https://www.google.com/search?q=pasteurization%20temperature%20table%20&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwicjb6Gsp7yAhV75OAKHTHeDmYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pasteurization%20temperature%20table%20&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABAYUJiyLFjAtyxgq7ksaABwAHgAgAF5iAHpBJIBAzMuM5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=nDYOYZzPJvvIgwexvLuwBg&bih=507&biw=905)

[graphs](https://www.google.com/search?q=pasteurization%20cooling%20graph&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8xPKetZ7yAhUIchQKHT0TAWMQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pasteurization%20cooling%20graph&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CaCViaCWCPCmgAcAB4AIABaIgBaJIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=9TkOYfz1B4jkUb2mhJgG&bih=507&biw=905)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for not being more precise, but what I have to pasteurize is not food but a piece of equipment akin to a medical equipment (I have added italic part in parenthesis to make it clearer). Your answer seems nonetheless to apply as the "danger zone" from 5° to 60° would, I guess, still apply for equipment for which we want to remove pathogens. Could you confirm it please? Also I can easily have a fast cooling step. The problem is not here, it's just that I wondered if this step was useful for equipment as it is not mentioned on Wikipedia for the medical equipment.

Comment: I'd recommend that you select the pasteurization process and temperature that best suits your equipment. Study the temperature graph images, i'll add references. Some pasteurization processes take 40 minutes to cool. Industries deal with giant vats of 1-2 tonnes, so the cooling can be slow, their studies have established flash pasteurization national protocols and cooling times. see end graph and conclusion https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268799840_Investigation_on_a_Tunnel_Pasteurizer_for_Nocellara_del_Belice_Table_Olives_Obtained_with_the_Castelvetrano_Style_Process

Comment: the study is about table olive so it's food. Are you sure this is the  link you wanted to share?

Comment: Disinfecting medical equipment is not pasteurisation. Its 2 questions in one. Pasteurisation can use slow cooling. Medical equipments doesnt denature with heat so you sould keep long time close to 100C. At least 80C for 20 minutes is best.

Comment: @MagTun - the danger zone is a temp range where bacteria can rapidly multiply given an appropriate food source (e.g. in food). This should not apply to your "medical equipment", you should be able to get it almost entirely without substrate for the bacteria to grow in.

Comment: @bob1, thanks for this info, I thought the danger zone was related to the germs characteristics not the food sources, it makes more sense now. But still I wonder, what if I can't keeping heating long enough to remove entirely the bacteria. I am in a remote place with limited means and I can only keep the heat at around 60-70°C for 5-10min. Would a fast cooling steps help the pasteurization by creating a thermic shock for the germs or this fast cooling won't affect  the germs in anyways. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MagTun it doesn't affect the bacteria/yeast/fungi as far as I know. What is your end point here? How clean/sterile does it need to be? Have you looked at chemical cleaning methods instead - formaldehyde (1-4%), phenol (conc??), alcohol (70% 1-5 min) all work well in general with fairly fast times.

Comment: @bob, I have limited means as I am in a remote place. So I am trying to find a solution but apparently this won't work this way. Thanks!

Comment: Are you in an igloo or a place with no energy?

Comment: @DeltaEnfieldWaid, sorry didn't see your comment, yes I am in a place without access to energy